# Ember: Edit model object without setting isdirty

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember.js-2

This topic har been discussed on stackoverflow before, but not with latest version of ember data, I think. At least none of the suggestions I have found have worked for me.

I use the latest version of Ember and Ember data (versjon 2.13.0). I use the JsonApiAdapter.

**Scenario**

After I load a record from the server I want to do a few changes to some of its properties. These changes shall not make the record dirty, and the changed attributes shall not show up in the `record.changedAttributes()`. Any changes the user may do after that shall make the record dirty.

**Searching for a solution**

I have tried to manually change the isDirty flag, but it didn't do it. I have also tried to find the place in the ember data code that sets the state after a record has been loaded (because essentially I am trying to do the same thing) but I haven't found where it is.
I have also tried `record.send('pushedData')`, but I didn't change anything of the state of the record.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know 3 methods which allow to modify server's response without dirtying records:

1. You can override adapter's [handleResponse](https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html#method_handleResponse) method and make modifications right in payload.
2. You can override serializer's [normalize](https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html#method_normalize) method.
3. You can load records from server with Ember.$.ajax method, modify response and then pass it to store's [pushPayload](https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushPayload) method.

First two methods are good if you need to modify record after every load from server (no matter from what route/controller you do it). Both adapter and serializer can be model-specific. If you need to do it in only one place (controller or route), or if you need an access to route's/controller's variables - 3rd method is good.

I'm not aware about any way to mark record as dirty/not dirty. If you modify a record after it was stored, it becomes dirty.

Comment: Perfect.  pushPayload did the trick for me. I found that it may be used to modify existing records in the store by just sending the part of the payload that shall be modified.